# Javascript Tab keydown when pressed and hold tab, it flickers infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some simple keydown event handler on a group of inputs, like such

```
$('.a, .b, .c').on('keydown', function (e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case 9:
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if($('.a'))
                // focus next
            else if($('.b'))
                // focus next
            ....
            break;
    }
})
```

However when I press the tab and hold, the cursor flickers infinitely and the event does not fire anymore, I have to focus outside the window and comeback for it to stop.

Have been trying to figure it out for many a days now, can anyone shine some light on how do I stop this behaviour?

Ok guys i have edited the code and reproduced the error in which i found out the mistake and fixed the issue.. Here is the code producing the effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.c, .d').on('focus', function (e) {
                       if (e.relatedTarget) {
                            var v = $(this).val();
                           var n = v.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
                           $(this).val(n);
                          var $elementThis = $(this);
                          setTimeout(function () { $elementThis.select(); }, 50);
                       }
  });

    $('.a, .b').on('focus', function (e) {
       if (e.relatedTarget) {
          var $elementThis = $(this);
          setTimeout(function () { $elementThis.select(); }, 50);
        }
   });

  $('.a, .b, .c, .d').on('keydown', function(e) {
   var keycode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
   switch (keycode) {
          case 9:
          {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();

              if ($(this).hasClass('a')) { $('.b').focus();  } 
              else if ($(this).hasClass('b')) { $('.c').focus(); }
              else if ($(this).hasClass('c')) { $('.d').focus(); }
              else if ($(this).hasClass('d')) { $('.a').focus(); }

              break;
           }
      }
    })
});
```

The part that is giving me the problem is the

```
setTimeout(function () { $elementThis.select(); }, 50);
```

causing it to flicker non-stop.
I am finding an alternative to it. Any suggestions are welcome.

And please remove the downvote. I hope this insight will be of help to someone in the future.

Comment: Seems to be fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/r0g1vfjL/. Can you show us an example of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `return false;`-it, to prevent default `tab` behavior (`e.prevenDefault();` prevents bubling, not default keypress behavior)?

Comment: There is typo in your `e.keyCode` and `e.preventDefault()` https://jsfiddle.net/r0g1vfjL/2/

Comment: Are you still around?

Comment: yes, weekend i was out of station. Well it does not if i hold the tab. I will fetch an example

Comment: i have tried return false. And this is just a pseudo code. The full set of code have other events and maybe this will help, The tab works in an overlay ... The overlay sits on top of divs in absolute position.

Comment: Hello @Praveen Kumar can u fix the downvote? i already fixed and clarify the question. Sorry for the raw code i wrote before :)

Comment: @WickStargazer Are you around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake. It should be `e.keyCode`:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').on('keydown', function (e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {        // Change this. Also better to check if `e.which`
    case 9:
      e.preventDefault();    // Change this
      e.stopPropagation();
      if($('.a'))
        ;//focus next
      else if($('.b'))
        ;//focus next
      ....
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The full version:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').on('keydown', function (e) {
  var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
  switch(charCode) {
    case 9:
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if($('.a'))
        ;//focus next
      else if($('.b'))
        ;//focus next
      ....
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

key code should be accessed like this e.keyCode

```
$('.a, .b, .c').on('keydown', function (e) {
 switch(e.keyCode)
 {
  case 9:
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     if($('.a'))
     //focus next
     else if($('.b'))
     //focus next
     ....
     break;
 }
})
```